Transform from Bessel to WGS84
Is there direct transform possible from Bessel ellipsoid to WGS84?
This coordinate pair corresponds to same point on Earth but importing them for example in QGIS results in 100m shift.
Bessel (EPSG:4004):
B = 56‘ 56' 53.919”, (56.94831083)
L 24' 06' 31.898”, (24.10886056)
GRS-80 (EPSG:4661 or 4326)
B = 56' 56' 50.900", (56.94747212)
L = 24" 06’ 31.591", (24.10877524)
Why it can't handle direct transform for geographic coordinates?


Found out that this PROJ4 transformation is used so no actual transform is made. Noop seems to stand for No operation. Why?
Ballpark geographic offset from Unknown datum based upon the Bessel 1841 ellipsoid to WGS 84
Area of use: World
+proj=noop
